# Iterate over set and remove element if it is in another set and return array

Tags: javascript, loops, set

I am not sure what I am missing from my function here to remove elements in a a set. It seems the loop is not working as expected. If you have a more optimal solution O(1), please share. Thanks!

```
const dupArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d",'dog']

function transformSearchFields(fields) {
  let noDupes = new Set(fields)
  const searchData = new Set(['dog', 'a'])

  // iterate over noDupes set and check if element is in the searchData set. If it is, remove the element from the noDupes set
  noDupes.forEach(element => {
    if (element in searchData) {
        noDupes.delete(element)
    }
  })

  return [...noDupes]
  }
// desired output: ["b", "c", "d"]
```

I expected the loop to remove values that were in the searchData set

Comment: Add some debugging: in the noDupes.forEach add `console.log(element, element in searchData)`

Comment: Where did you determine that `in` would do `.has` for Set?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was trying to use Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a value is "in" a Set, use .has()

> [.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)
>
> The has() method returns a boolean indicating whether an element with the specified value exists in a Set object or not.

In your case this would be:

```
if (searchData.has(element)) {
```

Updated snippet

```js
const dupArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", 'dog']

function transformSearchFields(fields) {
  let noDupes = new Set(fields)
  const searchData = new Set(['dog', 'a'])

  // iterate over noDupes set and check if element is in the searchData set. If it is, remove the element from the noDupes set
  noDupes.forEach(element => {
    //console.log(element, element in searchData, searchData.has(element))
    if (searchData.has(element)) {
      noDupes.delete(element)
    }
  })

  return [...noDupes]
}
console.log(transformSearchFields(dupArr));
```

There are other methods filter data (as provided in other answer, so not repeated here).

Answer (score 2):

Here is example how you can filter an array with unique values in response:

```js
const inputArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'dog'];
const dataToReject = ['dog', 'a'];

const filteredUniqueArray = [...new Set(
  inputArray.filter(inputArrayElement =>
    !dataToReject.some(dataToRejectElement => 
      inputArrayElement == dataToRejectElement
    )
  )
)];

console.log(filteredUniqueArray); // ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the `Set` directly and omit items of this the for filtering.

```js
function transformSearchFields(fields) {
    return fields.filter(
        (s => v => !s.has(v) && s.add(v))
        (new Set(['dog', 'a']))
    );
}

console.log(transformSearchFields(["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", 'dog'])); // b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dupArr Set to array again with spread operator and use `filter` with the `has` method for your searchData Set

```js
const transform = (fields, searchData) => [...new Set(fields)].filter(el => !searchData.has(el));


const searchData = new Set(['dog', 'a']);
const dupArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d",'dog']

console.log(transform(dupArr,searchData));
```